# MySQL St_distance_Sphere function

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query a small table to find all the records in the table that are within 1Km of the inputted coordinate point. Each record in the table has a 'Lat' and 'Long' column with the respective points. My query is

```
var sql = `SELECT * FROM GeoTest WHERE st_distance_sphere(POINT(-100,35),POINT(Long,Lat)) <= 1000`
```

> error 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near \'Long,Lat)) <= 1000\'

Data in the table

```
id        Lat                 Long

1   30.5092060000000000 -97.6046760000000000
2   31.1310390000000000 -97.7805610000000000
```

I do not know how to use the returned latitude and longitude from the selected row to compare the distance and then only return the record if it is within 1Km. How can I substitute the Long and Lat fields from the record into the st_distance_sphere function? I am sure I am missing something very simple here. Thanks for helping this SQL noob!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this works with 5.7 and 8.0

```
   Select st_distance_sphere(POINT(-100,35),
   POINT ( `Long` , `Lat`) ) From GeoTest;
```

Comment: I am gettin this error  'Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geometryfromtext.' I have tried with a column where the data is a double and where the data is a string but get the same error

Comment: Edit you post and show us your actual data. eventually you have to use GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT (', Long, ' ', Lat, ')'))

Comment: I posted the table data

Comment: Ok i change it to fit your data. but none of them are smaller as 1000 and usually the distance is divide by 1000.